# merging an array into another array

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying to manage arrays, but somehow I can't seem to make it work.

Here's my problem :
I have one array with a product, like this :

```
    array (size=2)
  'count' => string '1' (length=1)
  'records' => 
    array (size=5)
      'care_Id' => string '11938' (length=5)
      'productName' => string 'The name of the product blabla' (length=35)
      'productPrice' => string '98.00' (length=5)
      'beginAt' => string '2010-09-17 09:00:00' (length=19)
      'endAt' => string '2010-09-27 23:59:00' (length=19)
```

and another array with associative infos about the product, like this :

```
array (size=5)
  'sellQuantity' => string '22' (length=2)
  'validatedQuantity' => string '22' (length=2)
  'lostQuantity' => string '0' (length=1)
  'remainQuantity' => string '0' (length=1)
  'turnover' => string '2177.00' (length=7)
```

What I want to do would output this :

```
    array (size=2)
  'count' => string '1' (length=1)
  'records' => 
    array (size=5)
      'care_Id' => string '11938' (length=5)
      'productName' => string 'Journée Semaine Luxe et Bien-être' (length=35)
      'productPrice' => string '98.00' (length=5)
      'beginAt' => string '2010-09-17 09:00:00' (length=19)
      'endAt' => string '2010-09-27 23:59:00' (length=19)
      'sellQuantity' => string '22' (length=2)
      'validatedQuantity' => string '22' (length=2)
      'lostQuantity' => string '0' (length=1)
      'remainQuantity' => string '0' (length=1)
      'turnover' => string '2177.00' (length=7)
```

But I can't manage to do it. I've tried that :

```
$aTest = array_merge($aCares[$i]['records'], $aCaresInfo[$i]);
```

Here is the loop im using :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($aInSaleCares);$i++)
{
    $aFilter['careId'] = $aInSaleCares[$i]['careId'];
    $aCares[] = sthORM::get('Sales')->getInSaleCares($iOffset, $iLimit, array(), $aFilter);
    $aCaresInfo[] = sthORM::get('Sales')->getCaresInfo($aFilter);
    $aTest = array_merge($aCares[$i]['records'], $aCaresInfo[$i]);
}
```

But when I `var_dump` $aTest, it triggers an really strange error :

```
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in
```

But `var_dump(is_array($aCares[$i]['records']))` returns true ?

So my question is : How can I get the output I want exactly?

---

EDIT :

---

ive tried this too :

```
 $aTest[] = $aCares[$i]['records'] + $aCaresInfo[$i]; // inside of the loop
```

but when I print it outside of the loop, it returns a php fatal error :

```
Unsupported operand types
```

while inside the loop I correctly get datas like this :

```
array (size=10)
  'care_Id' => string '11938' (length=5)
  'productName' => string 'Journée Semaine Luxe et Bien-être' (length=35)
  'productPrice' => string '98.00' (length=5)
  'beginAt' => string '2010-09-17 09:00:00' (length=19)
  'endAt' => string '2010-09-27 23:59:00' (length=19)
  'sellQuantity' => string '22' (length=2)
  'validatedQuantity' => string '22' (length=2)
  'lostQuantity' => string '0' (length=1)
  'remainQuantity' => string '0' (length=1)
  'turnover' => string '2177.00' (length=7)
```

Comment: Please post your `for` loop where this `$i` is iterated.

Comment: Surely, if the error says that it's not an array, it's not an array :) btw, instead of `array_merge()` you could use `$aTest = $aCares[$i]['records'] + $aCaresInfo[$i];`

Comment: thanks @Jack but it returns : Unsupported operand types
when I print $aTest outside of the loop. but when I print it inside all works perfectly

Comment: Because outside of the loop the value of `$i` is undefined; it helps to have `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script to show all warnings.

Comment: @Jack but then, what do I need to do to reuse the array outside of the loop, for exemple if I want to print it?
loop() {
    $aTest[] = $aCares[$i]['records'] + $aCaresInfo[$i];
    var_dump($aTest); //works perfectly
}
var_dump($aTest); // fatal error

Comment: Okay I fixed the problem, it was my bad. Sometimes, $aCares[$i]['records'] aint an array but a false value, which was messing up the array + array thing. My bad, thank you @Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does $aTest exist outside the loop? Are you putting the contents of $aTest into something else outside of the loop and just not including it in your example?

```
$stuff = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($aInSaleCares);$i++)
{
    $aFilter['careId'] = $aInSaleCares[$i]['careId'];
    $aCares[] = sthORM::get('Sales')->getInSaleCares($iOffset, $iLimit, array(), $aFilter);
    $aCaresInfo[] = sthORM::get('Sales')->getCaresInfo($aFilter);
    $aTest = array_merge($aCares[$i]['records'], $aCaresInfo[$i]);
    $stuff[] = $aTest;
}

var_dump($stuff);
```

When all else fails, you could also try:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($aInSaleCares);$i++)
{
    $tmp = array();
    $aFilter['careId'] = $aInSaleCares[$i]['careId'];
    $aCares[] = sthORM::get('Sales')->getInSaleCares($iOffset, $iLimit, array(), $aFilter);
    $aCaresInfo[] = sthORM::get('Sales')->getCaresInfo($aFilter);

    $tmp = $aCares[$i]['records'];
    $tmp = array_merge($tmp, $aCaresInfo[$i]);

    // overwrite the existing contents of 'records'
    $aCares[$i]['records'] = $tmp;

}
```

Comment: even tho I had already solved the problem, your answer is correct and its the only one so ill accept it as it may help others. Thanks.

Comment: lol, thanks ;) It's not the most elegant edits to the code, but it would help change the error output to be more helpful as to what isn't an array.